# pidgin, invisible....but to everyone? Can it be customized?

Tags: pidgin

I was wondering if MSN can be customized in Piding?
I mean I am invisible....but to everyone, I simply cannot figure out how to be invisible only to certain people or groups.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the "Allow only the users below" and "block only the users below" privacy lists. It's possible it's buggy, but that's covered in bug #466 and #4454. And the fact that the privacy lists aren't labeled as "invisible" and "visible" lists will be dealt with in our privacy rewrite.

You can read more at http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/4878

Comment: thanks for the answer. One more question: to the "Allow only the users below" list....do I simply add the email of the users I want to appear visible to? And then set my status to visible from invisible?

Comment: Yes i believe so